# PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK with ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I read [PowerManager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) Doc which said "In addition, you can add two more flags, which affect behavior of the screen only. These flags have no effect when combined with a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK."

So `ON_AFTER_RELEASE` and `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` not work with `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`.

But why in google alarm module [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_alarmclock/blob/master/src/com/android/alarmclock/AlarmAlertWakeLock.java) , they used them together:

```
sCpuWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, Log.LOGTAG);
```

Comment: The code you link to is *at least* 7 years old. Don't use it as a reference. Trust the docs.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yeh. But the problem is when I implemented google alarm module in my own code .... it works :(  So a little lost here